# when page break in htmltopdfmake the row was broken

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, html-to-pdf, pdfmake

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0CjC.png)

check that given image , the table row was split into two pages.  I tried the below-mentioned CSS to solve this issue. but it wasn't solved.

```
style="page-break-inside: avoid; page-break-before: always;"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.